# Use child method from the parent class c++

Tags: c++, parent

Here's the deal. Imagine your as follows bellow.
After loading the files to the algorithm layer I want to be 
able to apply the 4 different algorithms. So the Algorithm class  has 4 children and I want to do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Data *data = new Data();
    Parent *alg = new Parent(data);

    alg->start();

    //and this will call the start methods defined in each child. 
}
```

The children are like this:

```
class Child1: public Parent {
public:
   int start();
}

class Child2: public Parent {
public:
   int start();
}
//etc...
```

And what I do in the Parents start() method is this:

```
int Parent::start() {
    Child1::start();
    Child2::start();
    //etc....
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting a 'cannot call member function 'Child1::start()', etc.. without object.'
Can this thing be done somehow? Calling a child method from the parent class?

Comment: I have no idea what problem you are trying to solve.  Can you please edit your question to explain what you are doing and what difficulties you have?

Comment: What is this `Child1,2,3,4` syntax? Can `,` be part of C++ identifiers now?

Comment: instead of writing the full thing, i'm using shortcuts... No it's not part of C++

Comment: If your parent class is aware of its children classes, you most likely have a design problem.

Comment: Did you hear about the Template Function pattern already?

Comment: You clearly noticed that you can't call the member functions `Child1::start()` etc without applying them to an object. The fonctions are said *non-static*. Use the keyword `static` in their declaration if you don't want them to be bound to an object.

Comment: Aw, closed on me. What you probably need is a Mixin, à la `template <class... Children> struct Algorithm : Children... {};`

Comment: Just don't do that. If you ask for help, the least you can do is to clearly write a Simple, Self-Contained Example that works, and not add your "clever" shortcuts to the mess that you need to solve.

Comment: I figured it was easy to understand. I wrote it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Take a look at the "Gang of Four" *composite* pattern:

The Child classes should not be derived from the Parent class.
Instead, Child and Parent classes should implement the same Interface,
let's call it `IAlgorithm`.
This Interface should have a pure `virtual` method `start()`...

Here is an example (using C++11 `auto` and Range-based for loop):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* parents and children implement this interface*/
class IAlgorithm {
public:
   virtual int start() = 0;
};

class Parent : public IAlgorithm {
private:
    std::vector<IAlgorithm*> children;
    
public:
    void addChild(IAlgorithm* child) {
        children.push_back(child);
    }

    int start() {
        std::cout << "parent" << std::endl;
        for (auto child: children)
            child->start();
        return 0;
    }
};

class Child1 : public IAlgorithm {
public:
    int start() {
        std::cout << "child 1" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};

class Child2 : public IAlgorithm {
public:
    int start() {
        std::cout << "child 2" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }
};

class Child3 : public IAlgorithm {
public:
    int start() {
        std::cout << "child 3" << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }
};

int main()
{
   Parent parent;
   Child1 child_1;
   Child2 child_2;
   Child3 child_3;
   
   parent.addChild(&child_1);
   parent.addChild(&child_2);
   parent.addChild(&child_3);
   
   parent.start();
   
   return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
parent
child1
child2
child3
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This is great!

Answer (score 0):

A parent can not call child methods, generally. In this case you've created the class as the parent type, so it would be pretty dangerous to call something in a child since a child may assume member methods or variables exist that aren't in the parent.

Comment: You said "generally" but can it be done in some way?

Comment: A child class can not be smaller in memory size than a parent, since it must contain everything in the parent. If a child adds a member variable then the child will be larger. When you create the class as the parent it only reserves enough space for that type of class, and if the child tries to access something that isn't in the parent it would be reading past the end of the reserved memory space, which can cause a crash.

Comment: You could use reinterpret_cast on the this pointer to call the member functions of a different class. I can pretty much 100% guarantee that you don't want to. You need more information in your question for people to know how it would be best to restructure your code to make this work.

Comment: I'm a newbie, that's just what I've been told to do and I'm trying to figure it out