# C++, How to call a child method in the parent class

Tags: c++, parent, hierarchy

I have two classes in my project:

- **Style**
- **Line**

In which, **Line is the child of Style**, so Line inherits from Style.

I need that when I call a method of the class Style (the parent) from Line (the child), the method of Style calls a method of the child, for your better understanding here is the code:

```
Line calls the Style function --> Style calls the Line function
```

*Style.h:*

```
#pragma once
class Style
{
    public:
        void set_size(int width, int height);

    protected:
        int width, height;
};
```

*Style.cpp:*

```
#include "Style.h"
void Style::set_size(int width, int height)
{
    Style::width = width;
    Style::height = height;
}
```

*Line.h:*

```
#pragma once
#include "Style.h"

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Line : public Style
{
    public:
        void draw();

        vector <vector<char>> matrix;
};
```

*Line.cpp:*

```
#include "Line.h"

void Line::draw()
{
    vector <char> row;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < Line::height; i++)
    {
        row.clear();

        for (j = 0; j < Line::height; i++)
        {
            row.push_back('-');
        }

        Line::matrix.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

*Main.cpp:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Line.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Line line;
    line.set_size(10, 10);
}
```

Obviously, this code for now does nothing much, it only modifies Style variables.

**What I expect is that when I call set_size(), in addition to changing the value of the variables width and height, it will also change the size of the matrix**

I don't know how to do what I said before.

I don't even know if it is a good method that Line is a child of Style, in any case other solutions that do not include inheritance are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say that "A is the child of B", do you mean that `B` inherits from `A`? Can you please try to create a [mre] to show us?

Comment: Seems that what you need is to make `aFunction` virtual.

Comment: I feel the way you have articulated the question is quite confusing.
so you expect B's _bfunction_  to run when you say `a.bfunction()`. is that correct?

Comment: @RC0993 This is why posters should post **real compilable code** not descriptions of code, which are always confusing.

Comment: For everyone, i'm editing my question

Comment: @Titan Just post some real code, with `cout << ` in the various functions to show when they are being called, and then say what you expect the output to be. That way there is no confusion.

Comment: @Titan  Can you replace the choice of class names from A & B to Base and Derived and let us clearly know the Expected and actual observations?

Here I dont have a clue for what `aFunction` is doing at all and why even is it there?

Comment: @john I agree !!!

Comment: You'll need objects to call non-static member functions. You can make the member functions static but then you may indeed not need inheritance, as you suspected. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974008/use-child-method-from-the-parent-class-c?rq=1 is what you want (it is among the linked questions to the right).

Comment: Does only `a.bFunction` call the function in `A`, not `bFunction` of other children? Then you just override `bFunction` in `A`. No need for virtual functions.

Comment: `Line` has a `Style` instead of `Line` is a `Style`. Composition would be more natural. But if you mean `StyledObject` or `StyledTool`, *is a* would apply and inheritance be more natural again.

Comment: @Sebastian, As I said, I do not know whether inheritance is the best solution, so I also accept solutions that do not involve inheritance

Comment: For everyone, I edited my post, added more code, changed the name of the classes and said what I expect as output.

Comment: You would also define `set_size` in `Line` and call `Style::set_size` from within `Line::set_size` and also change the matrix size there.

Comment: @Titan, see if [this](https://godbolt.org/z/v8xnzx79G) helps. using friend class. Or you can change to friend function

Comment: @RC0993, I have seen the code, but what I am trying to avoid is calling two functions one to change the values and the other to draw the matrix.

I would like everything to be done with one function call

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I'm completely changing the original answer since the question was modified too. If I get it right, you would like `line.set_size(...)` to call first the parent method and then to update the matrix. You cannot do that, because only one method will be called, and not both of them what you could do is add a `set_size` method for Line that calls Style's one.

*line.h* should be changed like this:

```cpp
class Line : public Style
{
public:
    void draw();
    void set_size(int width, int height);

    vector<vector<char>> matrix;
};
```

and you should append this to *line.cpp*:

```cpp
void Line::set_size(int width, int height)
{
    // call parent method
    Style::set_size(width, height);
    // now update matrix
    int i, j;
    matrix.resize(height);
    for (auto &row : matrix)
    {
        row.resize(width);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please, look at my post, I have edited it completely so that it is more compresnsitive

Comment: Raw `new`/`delete` should be avoided (except for low-level code). `std::unique_ptr` should be preferred in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to have implementation and declaration in the same file. but you can structure it as you may feel good for your project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Line;

class Style
{
    public:
        void set_size(int width, int height){
            w = width;
            h = height;
        }

        void print(){
            cout << w << ", " << h << endl;
        }

    friend class Line;

    protected:
        int w, h;
};

class Line : public Style
{
    public:
        void draw(){
            vector <char> row;
            int i, j;

            for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                row.clear();

                for (j = 0; j < h; i++)
                {
                    row.push_back('-');
                }

                matrix.push_back(row);
            }
        }

        vector<vector<char>> matrix;
};

int main()
{
    Line line;
    line.set_size(10, 10);
    line.print();
    line.set_size(20, 20);
    line.print();

}
```

Comment: Not sure, if the OP needs dynamic or only static polymorphism. One could mention that this solution provides dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: I have seen the code, but what I am trying to avoid is calling two functions one to change the values and the other to draw the matrix. I would like everything to be done with only one function call.

Comment: @Titan, I just tried to give an example of what can be done using friend class/function. making it optimal for your project is upto you. There arent 2 calls required if you dont want to. `friend` is to let a class use another class's variables and methods

Answer (score 0):

You need virtual functions, it would seem that `set_size` is the one that should be virtual, but this is not the only way to do it.

```
class Style
{
    public:
        virtual void set_size(int width, int height);
        virtual ~Style() {}
    protected:
        int width, height;
};

class Line : public Style
{
    public:
        void draw();
        virtual void set_size(int width, int height)
        {
            Style::set_size(width, height);
            ... // some code to resize matrix
        }
        vector <vector<char>> matrix;
};
```

But I question if this is good design, `Style` should be an **attribute** of `Line` (i.e. a member variable). Inheritance doesn't seem appropriate here, which is why you are struggling to write the code.

Comment: Write the code as you see fit, as already mentioned I also accept alternative solutions, which do not include inheritance, if you can do that, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

We can just overload `set_size` within `Line` and call the other `set_size` from there and also the draw function to recreate the matrix.

This solution provides simple static polymorphism, that means a `Line` cannot be assigned to a `Style` - you probably do not need this? So the compiler always statically at compile-time knows, which class an object really is and can call the correct member function. No virtual member functions are needed.

There also were bugs in the `draw` function, which I corrected below.

The changes to your code are marked with a comment in the following.

// Line.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Style.h"

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Line : private Style // use private inheritance for static polymorphism
{
    public:
        void draw();
        void set_size(int width, int height); // overload set_size (override only for virtual functions)

        vector <vector<char>> matrix;
};
```

// Line.cpp

```
#include "Line.h"

void Line::set_size(int width, int height)
{
    Style::set_size(width, height); // call set_size() function of style
    draw(); // draw() to set matrix to new size
}

void Line::draw()
{
    Line::matrix.clear(); // clear matrix, if draw() is called more than once

    vector <char> row;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < Line::height; i++)
    {
        row.clear();

        for (j = 0; j < Line::width; j++) // use Line::width and j++ (there were bugs)
        {
            row.push_back('-');
        }

        Line::matrix.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

// Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Line.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Line line;
    line.set_size(10, 10); // calls the enhanced Line::set_size

    // The following compilation errors (when the comments are removed) are good, as they prevent wrong usage of the current class definitions
    // Style style = line; // would give error, as we have private inheritance and want to prevent 'slicing' and the calling of the wrong member functions; if a Line should be able to be assigned to a Style, you need public dynamic inheritance and virtual functions, as provided in other answers. If you do not need to assign a Line to a Style, use the simpler implementation from this answer.
    // Style* stylepointer = &line; // also would give an error
}
```

Optionally `draw()` and `matrix` can be made private in `Line`.

If you need to call functions (other than set_size) of `Style` directly, you can use public inheritance, but make all constructors (including default/copy/move) of `Style` protected, so that only children like `Line` can call them. This would also prevent assignments of `Line` to `Style`.

Answer (score -1):

Base function must be virtual for runtime inheritance.
as follows example

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "print base class\n";
    }
  
    void show()
    {
        cout << "show base class\n";
    }
};
  
class derived : public base {
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "print derived class\n";
    }
  
    void show()
    {
        cout << "show derived class\n";
    }
};
  
int main()
{
    base *bptr;
    derived d;
    bptr = &d;
  
    // Virtual function, binded at runtime
    bptr->print();
  
    // Non-virtual function, binded at compile time
    bptr->show();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)